# how to change data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have record like below

```
entrydate
20161231
20161230
20161229
20161228
```

i need record like below

```
entrydate
2016-12-31 00:00:00.000
2016-12-30 00:00:00.000
2016-12-29 00:00:00.000
2016-12-28 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 1):

Use can use `CONVERT()` like:

```
select CONVERT(datetime,entrydate,108)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use cast function as below

```
DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(10)='20161230'

SELECT CAST(@STR AS DATETIME)
```

If you are using Sql Server 2012 Version then use below query

```
 SELECT TRY_CAST(@STR AS DATETIME)
```

Try_Cast will handle the invalid data also. If you pass some invalid data, it will return NULL.

Answer (score 1):

As easy as:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,entrydate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, hope this will work for you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    ;WITH tb(entrydate)AS(
       SELECT '20161231' UNION
       SELECT '20161230' UNION
       SELECT '20161229' UNION
       SELECT '20161228'
    )
    SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, STUFF(STUFF(tb.entrydate,5,0,'/'),8,0,'/')) FROM tb
```

```
-----------------------
2016-12-28 00:00:00.000
2016-12-29 00:00:00.000
2016-12-30 00:00:00.000
2016-12-31 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
SELECT CAST(entrydate AS DATETIME) AS entrydate FROM tablename;
```